# Prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac1{k^3}<\frac{11}{8}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Prove that $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{\frac1{k^3}}<\frac{11}{8}$$

Preferably, use Telescoping Series concept.

Comment: This isn't a homework site. Show what you have tried to get a favourable response.

Comment: Note that the infinite sum is [Apéry's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant), which is approximately $1.20205$. The bound $\frac{11}{8}=1.375$ is not so bad.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $$\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac1{k^3}}<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac1{k^3}}=\frac11+\left(\frac18+\frac1{27}\right)+\left(\frac1{64}+\frac1{125}+\frac1{216}+\frac1{343}\right)+\cdots \\ < \frac11+\left(\frac18+\frac1{8}\right)+\left(\frac1{64}+\frac1{64}+\frac1{64}+\frac1{64}\right) +\cdots $$

I'll leave it to you to transform this idea in a proper proof.

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Use the fact that for $k\geq 3$,
$$\frac{1}{k^3}<\frac{1}{k(k-1)(k-2)}=\frac{A}{(k-2)(k-1)}-\frac{B}{(k-1)k}$$
for some constants $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 3):

Not telescoping, but elementary (and gives Macavity's $5/4$ bound):

$$1+{1\over8}+{1\over27}+{1\over64}+\cdots\lt1+{1\over8}+\int_2^\infty{dx\over x^3}={9\over8}-\left({1\over2x^2}\Big|_2^\infty \right)={9\over8}+{1\over8}={5\over4}\lt{4\over3}\lt{11\over8}$$

(The $4/3$ between $5/4$ and $11/8$ is for comparison with lhf's integral-based bound.)

Comment: I think that $9/8+1/8$ is very clearly less than $11/8$. Nice easy argument, though!

Answer (score 2):

Not an elementary solution, but just for fun:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac1{k^3}}
< \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac1{k^3}}
= \zeta(3)
= \frac{2}{3}\int\limits_0^\infty \! \frac{x^2}{e^x+1}\, dx 
< \frac{2}{3}\int\limits_0^\infty \! \frac{x^2}{e^x}\, dx 
= \frac{4}{3}
< \frac{11}{8}
$$

The integral representation for $\zeta(3)$ appears in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant#Simple_formulas).

Comment: @wythagoras's answer gives an elementary proof that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac1{k^3}} < \frac{4}{3}$.  
I wonder which solution naturally gives $\dfrac{11}{8}$.

Comment: Telescoping using $\frac1{k^3} < \frac1{k(k-1)(k-2) } = \frac12\frac1{k}-\frac1{k-1}+\frac12\frac1{k-2}$ will give $\frac{11}8$

Comment: Have added an answer with this in it, felt I should add something more, so made a tighter bound also...

Answer (score 2):

You already have good answers.  Just another way for a tight bound... for $k> 1$,
$$k^3 > k^3-k \implies \frac1{k^3} < \frac1{(k+1)k(k-1)} = \frac12\frac1{k+1} - \frac1k + \frac12 \frac1{k-1}$$
which nicely telescopes.  So
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^3} &< (1) + \left(\color{red}{\frac12\frac13} - \frac12 + \frac12\frac11 \right) + \left(\frac12\frac14 - \color{red}{\frac13} + \frac12\frac12 \right) + \left(\frac12\frac15 - \frac14 + \color{red}{\frac12\frac13} \right) + \\ &\qquad\cdots + \left(\frac12\frac1{n+1} - \frac1n + \frac12\frac1{n-1} \right)\\
 &= \frac54 -\frac12 \left(\frac1n - \frac1{n+1}\right) < \frac54 < \frac{11}8
\end{align}
$$

---

If we start similarly with the less tight 
$$\frac1{k^3} < \frac1{k(k-1)(k-2)} = \frac12\frac1k - \frac1{k-1} + \frac12 \frac1{k-2}$$
we would get the bound $\frac{11}8$ directly.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=m}^n\frac1{k^3}=\int_m^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\lfloor x\rfloor^3}<\int_m^{n+1}\frac{dx}{(x-1)^3}<\frac1{2(m-1)^2}.$$

Then with $m=3$,

$$S_n<1+\frac1{2^3}+\frac1{2\cdot2^2}=\frac{10}8.$$

---

Just for fun, the next bounds are

$$1+\frac1{2^3}+\frac1{3^3}+\frac1{2\cdot3^2}=\frac{263}{216}$$

and

$$1+\frac1{2^3}+\frac1{3^3}+\frac1{4^3}+\frac1{2\cdot4^2}=\frac{2089}{1728}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
As $\color{#66f}{\texttt{@lhf}}$ said: "Just for fun":
\begin{align}
\zeta\pars{3} & = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{3}} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k - 1}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over x}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{x^{k} \over k^{2}}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & <
\int_{0}^{1}\braces{\vphantom{\Large A}1 + \bracks{\vphantom{\large A}\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1} - 1}x }\,\dd x\ =\
\underbrace{{1 \over 2} + {\pi^{2} \over 12}}
_{\ds{\approx\ \color{#f00}{1.3225}}}\ <\ {11 \over 8} = \color{#f00}{1.375}
\end{align}

---

$$\bbox[10px,#ffd,border:1px groove navy]{\ds{\zeta\pars{3} = 1.202056903159594\ldots}}
$$

---

> A further refinement is given by

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1/2}\braces{1 + 2\bracks{2\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2} - 1}x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] +&\
\int_{1/2}^{1}\braces{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1} + 2\bracks{2\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2} - \,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1}}\pars{1 - x}}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 4} + {\pi^{2} \over 8} - {1 \over 2}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2} \approx
\color{#f00}{1.2435}
\end{align}